# Export first frame from a GIF to PNG

Tags: python, ruby, png, gif

I thought you maybe could help me out here :-)
So I just launched my website, where I will upload some GIFs and have them displayed on the front page.
As of right now, I use a script to show a .png file, when a mouse is hovered, the .gif shows and you can click on it, which will link you to the .gif file.

So right now I got two files for every GIF; xxx.gif and xxx_thumb.png -- however, I would like this to get automatized and thought of a simple script.
In pseudo code:

```
get .gif
  rename to 1.gif
    if 1.gif taken? rename to 2.gif
  get first frame
    export first frame as 1_thumb.png
      if 1_thumb.png taken? rename to 2_thumb.png
load new picture? (y/n)
  if n
    exit
  if y
    start from step 1
```

Something like this would be awesome -- how hard would it be to code? Would Ruby or Python do the job?
Would this be possible with a web app, then send the .gif + .png as an email to me? <-- not necessary yet :-)

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904940/python-converting-gif-frames-to-png

Comment: Ruby would be very easy to use. So what happens if 2.gif is already taken? Would it go to 3.gif?

Comment: If you host the GIF on the same web server as your HTML, it would be very easy to draw an animated GIF to an HTML5 Canvas, then use `toDataURL()` to create a base64 encoding of PNG data. From there you could submit a form with that data to your server, decode the base64 and write the PNG to disk if desired.

Comment: Yup, just like that lkjoel -- if name is in use, add 1 and try again

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby you could check out [rmagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) and while [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-and-rmagick.htm) is for an older version of Rails it starts the process you would follow.