# Gifs opened with python have broken frames

Tags: python, gif

Sometimes when opening gifs and saving separate frames to files, the frames come out in bad shape. This doesn't happen with all the gifs, but with the ones that does it happens to many frames.

Example

Here's the original gif

[http://imgur.com/XMxW3m3](https://imgur.com/XMxW3m3)

Here's the first frame (comes out ok)

[http://imgur.com/xv43alb](https://imgur.com/xv43alb)

Here's the second frame (comes out screwed)

[http://imgur.com/hG4VxzL](https://imgur.com/hG4VxzL)

I tried the same thing with two different python modules. First PIL

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('pigs.gif')

counter = 0
collection = []
while True:
    try:
        img.save('original%d.gif' % counter)
        img.seek(img.tell()+1)
        counter += 1
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Then Wand:

```
from wand.image import Image

img = Image(filename='pigs.gif')

for i in range(len(img.sequence)):
    img2 = Image(img.sequence[i])
    img2.save(filename='original%d.gif' % i)
```

and the same happens with both modules.

What's going on?

P.S.:
I have found other people having the same symptoms. However, these solutions (both of which revolve around a bug of PIL which deletes the palette when you do .seek()) didn't solve my problem:
[Python: Converting GIF frames to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904940/python-converting-gif-frames-to-png)
and
[PIL - Convert GIF Frames to JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269099/pil-convert-gif-frames-to-jpg)

Answer (score 4):

In gifs a frame may contain only the pixels that changed in that frame. So when you export you get black where there was no change.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('pigs.gif')

counter = 0
collection = []
current = img.convert('RGBA')
while True:
    try:
        current.save('original%d.png' % counter)
        img.seek(img.tell()+1)
        current = Image.alpha_composite(current, img.convert('RGBA'))
        counter += 1
    except EOFError:
        break
```

EDIT: Changed output format to png as suggested in comments due to color palette problems that otherwise occur.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but that's not the whole story. It fixed the missing parts so I guess there's some truth in what you say, but it still comes out wrong, although in a different way:
http://imgur.com/rham3RW

Comment: Hi, I was still playing around with this and I noticed if you instead save the images are png, this method actually works perfectly. So, if you change your code to current.save('original0%d.png' % counter, 'PNG'), I will accept this answer as correct.
BTW, it seems that saving as png is MUCH slower than saving as gif. Why is that? Do you know how it can be saved as gif, to make it faster?

Comment: I created another question, in case you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996710/more-problems-extracting-frames-from-gifs

Comment: Layers can contain information if they are merged or replace the previous frame. I am not sure how to extract this information with pil/pillow