# More problems extracting frames from GIFs

Tags: python, gif

Following my previous question ([Gifs opened with python have broken frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990868/gifs-opened-with-python-have-broken-frames)) I now have code that works sometimes.

For example, this code

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('pigs.gif')

counter = 0
collection = []
current = img.convert('RGBA')
while True:
    try:
        current.save('original%d.png' % counter, 'PNG')
        img.seek(img.tell()+1)
        current = Image.alpha_composite(current, img.convert('RGBA'))
        counter += 1
    except EOFError:
        break
```

…works on most GIFs perfectly, but on others it produces weird results. For example, when applied to this 2-frame GIF:

[image: GIF]

It produces these two frames:

[image: Frame 1]
[image: Frame 2]

The first one is ok, the second one not so much.

What now?

Comment: Try viewing the second frame without composting it with the first and see if it's what it ought be as far as what pixels have changed and have not.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        current.save('original%d.gif' % counter)
        img.seek(img.tell()+1)
        current = img.convert('RGBA')
        counter += 1
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: You didn't really read the previous question, did you? My previous question was precisely that THAT code doesn't work.

Comment: Great. So then what is your question? What about either this approach or the approach that another SO'er provided is wrong?

Comment: In my question, I say what the question is: that code when applied to some gifs still produces a wrong result.

Comment: What is wrong about the result. The result you showed looks like compositing an image on top of another image. The solution I have should (presumably) be the image without compositing.

Comment: If you read my previous question, you'll see that the composition is necessary, because gif only saves changes from frame to frame. So what you have is not a "solution". Read the linked question please.

Answer (score 1):

try [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/) (Wand is a ctypes-based simple ImageMagick binding for Python.)

```
from wand.image import Image

def extract_frames(gif_file):
    with Image(filename=gif_file) as gif:
        for i, single_img in enumerate(gif.sequence):
            with Image(image=single_img) as frame:
                frame.format = 'PNG'
                frame.save(filename='frame-%d.png' % i)

extract_frames('test.gif')
```

[image: frame-0]

frame-0.png

[image: frame-1]

frame-1.png