# Imagemagick & Pillow generate malformed GIF frames

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I need to extract the middle frame of a gif animation.

Imagemagick:

```
convert C:\temp\orig.gif -coalesce C:\temp\frame.jpg
```

generates the frames properly:

[image]

However when I extract a single frame:

```
convert C:\temp\orig.gif[4] -coalesce C:\temp\frame.jpg
```

then the frame is malformed, as if the -coalesce option was ignored:

[image]

Extraction of individual frames with Pillow and ffmpeg also results in malformed frames, tested on a couple of gifs.

Download gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXkBn.gif

I need to be able to extract middle frames of every gif version in either PIL, Imagemagick of ffmpeg (ideally PIL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this script will find and save the middle frame of an animated GIF using Pillow.

It will also display the duration of the GIF by counting the milliseconds of each frame.

```
from PIL import Image

def iter_frames(im):
    try:
        i = 0
        while 1:
            im.seek(i)
            frame = im.copy()
            if i == 0:
                # Save pallete of the first frame
                palette = frame.getpalette()
            else:
                # Copy the pallete to the subsequent frames
                frame.putpalette(palette)
            yield frame
            i += 1
    except EOFError:  # End of gif
        pass

im = Image.open('animated.gif')
middle_frame_pos = int(im.n_frames / 2)
durations = []

for i, frame in enumerate(iter_frames(im)):
    if i == middle_frame_pos:
        middle_frame = frame.copy()

    try:
        durations.append(frame.info['duration'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

middle_frame.save('middle_frame.png', **frame.info)

duration = float("{:.2f}".format(sum(durations)))
print('Total duration: %d ms' % (duration))
```

Helpful code:

- [Python: Converting GIF frames to PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904940/python-converting-gif-frames-to-png/4905209#4905209)
- https://github.com/alimony/gifduration

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to coalesce a single input image into single output image.  What you got is what you asked for.

Instead you should "flatten" frames 0-4 into a single output image:

```
convert C:\temp\orig.gif[0-4] -flatten C:\temp\frame.jpg
```

If you use "-coalesce" you'll get 5 frames of output in frame-0.jpg through frame-4.jpg, the last of them being the image you wanted.

Comment: Doesn't work on a single frame "orig.gif[4]", as it generates a malformed frame.
the "-coalesce" is needed, because otherwise the subsequent frames skip the GIF pallete: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#coalesce. I have posted a working answer using PIL.

Comment: It works with a single frame but if the GIF is optimized it'll only show the parts that changed from the previous frame.  You have to use the range [0-N].

Comment: That's right, that's why a single frame appears malformed. The solution I posted copies the pallete for every frame, so it saves a single frame as it is in a playback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
convert pour.gif -coalesce -delete 0-3,5-8 frame4.png
```

[image]

Basically, it generates in full, all the frames and then deletes all frames other than from 4.

Comment: It works, as I showed in the original question. It doesn't work when you try to extract only a single frame pour.gif[2] or a range of frames pour.gif[2-5]

Comment: I can answer my question in 10 minutes. Thanks for heads up.