# Writing text on a GIF broke the GIF file

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I tried adding text to a `GIF` file but it seems to have messed up the file. When I now open it, it looks like what you get when you have white noise on an old TV, but with some bits still showing part of the original `GIF`. Could someone help me debug?

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
import numpy
import imageio

img = Image.open('test.gif')
sequence = []
frameNo = 0
while True:
  try:
    img.seek(frameNo)
  except EOFError:
    break

  newimg = Image.new("RGB", img.size)
  newimg.paste(img)

  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimg);

  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimg)
  # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
  font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 30
    )
  # draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
  draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)

  open_cv_image = numpy.array(newimg)
  sequence.append(open_cv_image)

  frameNo += 1

imageio.mimsave('temp.gif', sequence);
```

Comment: you have to `getpalette()` from first frame and `setpalette()` with all other frames. You can see resolve in some other question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613716/imagemagick-pillow-generate-malformed-gif-frames/35615319#35615319